# Fixed floating banner not working in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6, css-float

I'm trying to use this fixed floating banner script in IE6 -> [Demo](http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/fixedfloat.html)

According to [explanation](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/) of developer:

"Caveat: IE6

Since we’re solving this effect using position: fixed, IE6 doesn’t support this CSS property. I’m not saying that IE6 doesn’t matter, but I’m suggesting that this effect isn’t a requirement to be able to interact with the site properly, so if IE6 users don’t see this extra effect, I’m okay with this. As I explained in the screencast, you’ll need to decide this yourself, check your site’s demographic, whether it’s a personal project, etc."

Is this possible to adopt this effect in IE6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE6, you can use `position:absolute;` to work something like `position:fixed;`.

It will need a bit of additional markup in the shape of a wrapping `<div>`, but if you're supporting IE6 you'll be used to doing stuff like that anyway.

See here for instructions: http://ryanfait.com/resources/fixed-positioning-in-internet-explorer/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) - it's a javascript based css overhaul for older browsers.

There is a [css hack](http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6/) you could try:

```
* html .commentWrapper {
     position: absolute;
   }
```

Comment: Modernizr is great, but it doesn't actually fix browsers; it just helps you work around the missing features.

Comment: I know and sadly it doesn't do position:fixed for IE6 either - but still might help with other issues... the css hack should work

Comment: heh. you added that while I was busy answering with the same site :) +1 for you, then. Note - the css hack also requires adding a wrapper element.